# Trying to create Instagrams video uploading process

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, instagram

I am trying to figure out a way to recreate instagrams video uploading process. I would like for a user to be able to upload a video and trim it if necessary and then select an image from within the new video length. The images below reflect what i would like to accomplish (I don't really care about the Filter option).
[image]
[image]

If you could direct me to some libraries, tutorials, or give me any sort of guidance that you think will help me in this process that would be appreciated. Thx ahead of time.

Comment: Not obvious which part of the above you are struggling with...

Comment: Kinda all of it. So first off how should i go about trimming videos in React Native? The libraries I have found seem unmanaged and unused.

Comment: This is still kinda difficult in react native I would say. Although I made recently completely custom video player with trimmer using these libraries `react-native-video-processing`, `react-native-video` and `react-native-video-controls`. It's looots of custom code and it wan't be easy but it's possible. Unfortunately I can't give you more than that but I believe you can achieve what you described with these libraries.

Comment: Thx ill go ahead and take a look at react-native-video-processing. I know instagram uses react native so i was hoping that there would be a library that was more easily accessible.